# Using the survey package to find SE's and crosstabulations

Tags: r, survey

I am using the [survey package](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egmeeden/classes/5201/handouts/survey_handout.pdf) by Thomas Lumley to create cross tabs and SE's. I am struggling to specify the denominator of the cross tabulation.

##### This is my data:

```
    library(survey)
    data <- read_table2("Q50_1   Q50_2   Q38 Q90 pov gender  wgt id
    yes   3   Yes NA   High    M   1.3 A
    NA   4   No  2   Med F   0.4 B
    no   2   NA 4   Low F   1.2 C
    maybe   3   No  2   High    M   0.5 D
    yes   NA   No  NA   High    M   0.7 E
    no   2   Yes 3   Low F   0.56 F
    maybe   4   Yes 2   Med F   0.9 G")
```

##### Create the design object:

```
    design <- svydesign(id =~id,
                            weights  = ~wgt,
                            nest = FALSE,
                            data = data)
```

##### To find the cross tabulation of Q50_1 by Female:

```
svymean(~interaction(Q50_1,gender=="F"), design, na.rm = T)
```

This gives me:

```
                                                 mean     SE
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")maybe.FALSE 0.096899 0.1043
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")no.FALSE    0.000000 0.0000
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")yes.FALSE   0.387597 0.2331
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")maybe.TRUE  0.174419 0.1725
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")no.TRUE     0.341085 0.2233
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")yes.TRUE    0.000000 0.0000
```

This is not as useful to me because the denominator includes TRUE FALSE values for every combination, whereas I am only interested in the mean that is true. So, I could easily find the percentage of TRUE as follows:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(svymean(~interaction(Q50_1,gender=="F"), design, na.rm = T)) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("question")

dat %>%   tidyr::separate(question,c("question",'response'), sep = "\\)", extra = "merge") %>%
    mutate(question = str_replace(question,"interaction\\("," ")) %>%
    tidyr::separate(response,c('value', 'bool'), sep ="\\." ) %>% 
    tidyr::separate(question,c('question', 'group'), sep ="\\," ) %>% 
    tidyr::separate(group,c('group_level', 'group'), sep ="\\==" ) %>% 
    
    filter(bool=='TRUE') %>%
    group_by(question, group_level, group) %>%
    mutate(sum_true = sum(mean)) %>%
    mutate(mean= mean/sum_true)
```

This gives me:

```
  question group_level group    value bool   mean    SE sum_true
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 " Q50_1" " gender "  " \"F\"" maybe TRUE  0.338 0.173    0.516
 " Q50_1" " gender "  " \"F\"" no    TRUE  0.662 0.223    0.516
 " Q50_1" " gender "  " \"F\"" yes   TRUE  0     0        0.516
```

**The means are exactly what I want, *but the SEs are associated with a different denominator* and don't represent the manipulated mean. Is there a way to call the svymean to present the mean and SE of ONLY the TRUE values in the denominator?**

I thought something like this might do (but it does not work):

```
svymean(~interaction(Q50_1,gender=="F"[TRUE]), design, na.rm = T)
```

## My desired outcome (the SE's are fake):

```
                                                      mean     SE
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F"[TRUE])maybe.TRUE  0.338     0.0725
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F"[TRUE])no.TRUE     0.0.662   0.0233
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F"[TRUE])yes.TRUE    0.0       0.0000
```

Comment: What exactly is the calculation you want to do? You want the share of women who gave each of those answers (yes, no, maybe), so the denominator is all women? I'm confused by the true/false part, but is that because those answers are being converted to dummy variables?

Comment: @camille Yes, I want the percentage of women, who responded to each of the answers. Those variable being converted to dummies IS the problem---it's not just the share of women I am interested in, I want to get the SE of each share as well. For example, what is the SE of the share of women who answered 'maybe'? R gives out the SE as related to the entire dummy of possibilities...

Comment: Does `svyby(~Q50_1, ~gender, design, svymean, na.rm = T)` get you closer to what you want?

Comment: @camille Thank you!! For the most part it does! For example, you would expect these two lines of code to produce similar values, but the latter one shows me an "Error in contrasts": Line 1: survey::svymean(~interaction(Q50_1, ccs_type=="County Community"), subset(SurveyDesign1, CCS=="TRUE", grade_level %in% c("secondary","elementary")), na.rm = T)   Line 2: svyby(~Q50_1,~ccs_type,  subset(SurveyDesign1, CCS=="TRUE", grade_level %in% c("secondary","elementary")), svymean, na.rm= T)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the percentage of women who responded to each answer you want

```
svymean(~Q50_1, subset(design, gender== "F"),na.rm=TRUE)
```

or equivalently (because that's how `svyby` does it)

```
svyby(~Q50_1, ~gender, design, svymean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If you want to get the empty category as well, you need to convert the `~Q50_1` variable to a factor -- that's the point of factors (vs strings): they know what levels they have.

If you to be able to extract parts of the output programmatically, use the `coef` and `SE` functions

```
data$Q50_1<-factor(data$Q50_1)
design <- svydesign(id =~id,
                             weights  = ~wgt,
                             nest = FALSE,
                             data = data)
                             
 svymean(~Q50_1, subset(design, gender== "F"),na.rm=TRUE)
 svyby(~Q50_1, ~gender, design, svymean, na.rm = TRUE)[1,]

 coef(svyby(~Q50_1, ~gender, design, svymean, na.rm = TRUE)) 
 SE(svyby(~Q50_1, ~gender, design, svymean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

These don't agree with what you got using `~interaction`, because what you got that way doesn't match what you said you want.  The `interaction` analysis gives you the percentage of people who are women and also responded `yes`, not the percentage of `yes` responses among women.  To put it another way, the 6 percentages you get with the `interaction` analysis add to 100%, not to 200%.

```
> sum(coef(svymean(~interaction(Q50_1,gender=="F"), design, na.rm = T)))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is immensely helpful.